# How can i listen to input in very precise manner of microseconds. Like piscope. Using pigpio socket interface, pigs or liberary

Tags: java, pigpio, qt, pi-gpio

I want to get time and count of input pulse in microseconds using pigpio. How can i Listen to gpio pin in spreate thread.

Comment: Do you want to use pigpio?  If so what language do you want to use?  pigpio provides a C and Python API for the socket interface.  3rd parties provide Erlang, Java, Node.js, and Xojo interfaces.

Comment: Yes pigpio, c or java..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default pigpio samples GPIO 0-31 at a rate of 200 thousand times per second (once every 5µs).

You can register to be alerted when

1. one or more of GPIO 0-31 change level
2. one or more of GPIO 0-31 have not changed level for a timeout period

The pigpio daemon provides a socket interface to this information.  Each report contains an incrementing sequence number, flags to indicate a timeout, the event tick, and a bit mask giving the levels of GPIO 0-31 at that event tick.

The event tick is a 32 bit microsecond counter which starts at boot and wraps around every 1 hour 12 minutes.

[piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) is written in C and uses alerts via the socket inerface.

x_pigpiod_if2.c (part of the pigpio archive) is written in C gives examples of using alerts via the socket interface.

[monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py) is written in Python and uses alerts via the socket interface.

There are other [C socket interface examples](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pigpiod_if2%20code) and miscellaneous general pigpio [examples](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html).

Comment: Which files i have to import in c++  so i can use it in Qt. Where i can find them?

Comment: I can't help with that, I have no knowledge of Qt.

Comment: Just i want to know which header files i have to import in my c++ and where are they saved?